Solving for $z\cdot w$ and $\frac{z}{w}$ using the polar form of z and w
The problem:
Express each of the complex numbers $z=-1+i$ and $w=3i$ in polar form. Use these expressions to calculate $z\cdot w$ and $\frac{z}{w}$.
The answer:
$z\cdot w = -3-3i, \frac{z}{w} = \frac{1+i}{3}$
What I have tried:
I began by calculating the moduli and arguments of z and w and got the following:
$r_z={\sqrt2}, \theta_z = \frac{3\pi}{4}$
$r_w=3, \theta_w = \frac{\pi}{2}$
z and w expressed in polar form is thusly:
$z=\sqrt{2}(\cos{\frac{3\pi}{4}}+i\sin{\frac{3\pi}{4}})$
$w=3(\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}})$
I can reach the right answers by putting in $z = -1+i$ and $w=3i$ in the formulas for multiplication and division of complex numbers. But the question is asking me to use the polar form of the expressions to get to the answers. How am I expected to go about doing that?

If you can write $u = re^{i\theta}$ for the polar form, then this is easy. Otherwise - you should have a formula for multiplication that just reduces to an operation on the exponents.

Indeed I don't see any advantage using polar form, maybe they meant exponential form?

Try represent it as Cis, and use its properties for this. I was taught to use this method for the multiplication and division of complex numbers.

In the context of complex numbers, by taking advantange of Euler's formula the polar form can be written in either of the two formats $r , (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ or $r , e^{i\theta}$. It is easier to do multiplication and division with the latter format.

Hint:
$$z \cdot w = (r_z \cdot r_w) (\cos (\theta_z+\theta_w) + i \sin (\theta_z+\theta_w)) $$
$$\dfrac {z}{w} = \dfrac {r_z} {r_w} (\cos (\theta_z-\theta_w) + i \sin (\theta_z-\theta_w)) $$

Definitions
The point of the polar form—whether you write it as an exponential or in terms of trig functions doesn't matter—is that multiplication of complex numbers is especially intuitive and geometric.
Say that $z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$. Notice that the modulus (size/magnitude of the complex number) is:
$$
|z| = |r\cos\theta + i\,r\sin\theta| 
= \sqrt{r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta\,} 
= r \sqrt{\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta\,} 
= r
$$
And the argument (angle measured in standard position) is evidently
$\def\Arg{\operatorname{Arg}}
\Arg z = \theta$. This is really nice because the modulus contains all of the size information with no direction information, and conversely the argument contains all of the direction information without any size information. So the polar form factors a complex number $z$ into a size $|z|$ and a direction $\Arg z$.
Geometric meaning
But it gets better, and this gets to the heart of why complex multiplication is invented the way that it is. When we multiply two complex numbers, we can treat each part separately. First, some notation to agree with your prompt:
$$
z = r_z (\cos\theta_z + i\sin\theta_z) 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
w = r_w (\cos\theta_w + i\sin\theta_w).
$$

Multiply the moduli
$$
|zw| = |z| \, |w| = r_z \, r_w
$$
Add the arguments
$$
\Arg(zw) = \Arg z + \Arg w = \theta_z + \theta_w 
$$

Geometrically, when we multiply $w$ by $z$ (we start with $w$ as a vector in the complex plane), scale it by $|z|$ and rotate it by $\Arg z$. As a special case to really make the geometric meaning clear, if $w$ happens to be the real number $w = 1 = 1 + 0i$, so $|w| = |1| = 1$ and $\Arg w = \Arg 1 = 0$, then this just describes how we would plot $z$ using its polar information: magnitude $|z| \, |1| = z \cdot 1 = |z|$ and direction $\Arg z + \Arg w = \Arg z + 0 = \Arg z$.
Why does this work?
Ignoring the modulus for a moment, i.e., assuming $|z| = |w| = 1$, so they live on the unit circle:
$$
\begin{aligned} 
zw &= (\cos\theta_z + i\sin\theta_z) \, (\cos\theta_w + i\sin\theta_w) \\
&= (\cos\theta_z\cos\theta_w - \sin\theta_z\sin\theta_w) + i\,(\cos\theta_z\sin\theta_w + \sin\theta_z\cos\theta_w) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Do you recognize those last two expressions, the real and imaginary parts of the product $zw$? Yes, those are the sum-of-angles formulas, so we have
$$
zw = \cos(\theta_z+\theta_w) + i\,\sin(\theta_z+\theta_w).
$$
This shows that the arguments add!
Now, the fact that the moduli scale one another, I leave that to you work out or read somewhere.
A note about notation
This is one of the places where Euler's exponential form is very convenient as we already have an intuitive idea that when multiplying two exponential expressions, we add the exponents:
$$
(r_ze^{i\theta_z}) (r_we^{i\theta_w}) = (r_zr_w)e^{i(\theta_z+\theta_w)}.
$$
Division
Remember that division is the inverse of multiplication: $\frac{z}{w} = v$ means the same thing as $z = vw$ even if the quotient $v$ is unknown. So
$$
|z| = |vw| = |v| \, |w| 
\quad\implies\quad 
|v| = \frac{|z|}{|w|},
$$
and
$$
\Arg z = \Arg(vw) = \Arg v + \Arg w 
\quad\implies\quad 
\Arg v = \Arg z - \Arg w.
$$
Your particular examples
You have correctly decomposed the complex numbers into their polar form, so at this point, you should be able to just plug in the numbers and evaluate. Here's the product (try it yourself first):

 $$ \begin{aligned} zw &= |z|\,|w| \, \Arg(z + w) \\ &= r_zr_w \, \bigl(\cos(\theta_z + \theta_w) + i\,\sin(\theta_z+\theta_w) \bigr) \\ &= 3\sqrt{2} \, \bigl(\cos\tfrac{5\pi}{4} + i\,\sin\tfrac{5\pi}{4}\bigr) \\ &= 3\sqrt{2} \, \biggl(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\biggr) \\ &= -3 - 3i \end{aligned} $$

And you can work out the quotient yourself!

+1 : Nice long-winded answer, which (in my opinion) is just what the situation calls for.
